# Multiple streams in wcf

Tags: wcf, stream

I am trying upload multiple files using WCF. Since WCF only supports one stream I need to join multiple file streams together on the client and pass this to the service. 
The files might be huge and cannot be buffered in memory.

How do I do this? Please show some code sample if you have.

Regards,
Rune

Answer (score 2):

Since WCF allows only single stream parameter the only possible way I see is to combine multiple files as one stream and pass to the server, plus some extra info like file names, their lengths in the order they appended into stream.